# Left outer join with Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a person, which has a foreign key to `User`:

```
p = Personne.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

This person has "friends" through the model `PersonneRelation` where there's a `src` person and a `dst` person, so I'm retrieving all the person's friends like this:

```
friends = [a.dst.pk for a in PersonneRelation.objects.filter(src=p)]
```

I have a model `Travel` which embeds a description of a travel. I have also a model "activity" which is an activity the friend's current user have done (`Activite`). So here's the way I'm retrieving all the activities related to the current user:

```
context['activites'] = Activite.objects.filter(
    Q(travel__personne__pk__in=friends) | Q(relation__src__pk__in=friends),
)
```

Everything works fine. I have also a model `PersonneLiked` where you precise if you liked an `Activite`. Thus this model has a foreign key to `Activite`.

```
class PersonneLiked(models.Model):
    src = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='liked_src')
    dst = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='liked_dst')
    activite = models.ForeignKey('Activite', related_name='liked_activite')
    # liked = thumb added *OR* removed :
    liked = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

What is the code I should do to retrieve all the `PersonneLiked` of `context['activites']`? It's like making an `OUTER JOIN` in SQL, but I dont know how I could do this with Django.

Comment: why is this clause `Q(relation__src__pk__in=friends)`, and why PersonneLiked also has src and dst? Isn't the relation saved in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `context['activities']` is a queryset of the appropriate `Activite` objects then you can do:

```
PersonneLiked.objects.filter(activite__in=context['activities'])
```

(Note that if this were a M2M relationship rather than a ForeignKey, this method would create duplicate entries in your final queryset.)

Comment: `context['liked'] = [a.activite for a in PersonneLiked.objects.filter(
            activite__in=context['activites'],
            liked__exact=True)]`