# Django ORM - LEFT OUTER JOIN with two columns?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

This is the relevant code:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class BookNote(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('book', 'user'), ]
```

Now, for a specific user in the website:
I want to query **all** the books (all the table). And,
For each book object, If the user has a BookNote for the book - get it, otherwise booknote should be null.

This is how I would do that with SQL (works):

```
SELECT book.name, booknote.text 
FROM book 
LEFT OUTER JOIN booknote ON 
(book.id = booknote.book_id AND booknote.user_id = {user_id_here})
```

This is what I've tried, does **not** work:

```
qs = Book.objects.filter(Q(booknote__user_id=user_id_here) | Q(booknote__isnull=True))
```

I examine `qs.query` and I see why - Django uses WHERE clause to filter by user_id, so I don't get all the books.
How can I do the same query with django ORM? Without raw sql?

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338867/left-outer-join-with-django) out

Comment: Have you tried select_related?

Comment: The question you post does not answer me. As for select_related- does not help, it only fetches related objects, does not change the query itself

Answer (score 5):

The reason your query doesn't work is you're expicitly asking for either Books with your user's notes or no notes at all: this excludes books where only other users have notes.

I think what you're looking for is best performed as an annotation. Under django 2.0+, you can use the new FilteredRelation to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN ON (... AND ...)`, but I had trouble doing it and maintaining the ForeignKey in the ORM; you'll have to re-export the fields you need with additional annotations.

```
q =  Book.objects.all().annotate(
        usernote=FilteredRelation('booknote', condition=Q(booknote__user=USER_ID)),
        usernote_text=F('usernote__text'),
        usernote_id=F('usernote'),
        )
```

Resulting query:

```
SELECT "books_book"."id", "books_book"."name", usernote."text" AS "usernote_text", usernote."id" AS "usernote_id" FROM "books_book" LEFT OUTER JOIN "books_booknote" usernote ON ("books_book"."id" = usernote."book_id" AND (usernote."user_id" = <USER_ID>))
```

If you're using 1.11 still, you can get the same result (but less performance and different queries) with Prefetch objects <strike>or a case-when annotation</strike>.

In models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
     # SNIP
     @property
     def usernote(self):
         # raises an error if not prefetched
         try:
             return self._usernote[0] if self._usernote else None
         except AttributeError:
             raise Exception("Book.usernote must be prefetched with prefetch_related(Book.usernote_prefetch(user)) before use")

     @staticmethod
     def usernote_prefetch(user):
         return Prefetch(
             'booknote_set',
             queryset=BookNote.objects.filter(user=user)
             to_attr='_usernote'
         )
```

By your query:

```
    q = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related(Book.usernote_prefetch(USER))
```

Full `tests.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.test import TestCase
from django.db.models import *
from books.models import Book, BookNote
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class BookTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        self.u1 = User.objects.create(username="U1")
        self.u2 = User.objects.create(username="U2")
        self.b1 = Book.objects.create(name="B1")  # Has no notes
        self.b2 = Book.objects.create(name="B2")  # Has a note for U1 and U2
        self.b3 = Book.objects.create(name="B3")  # Has a note for just U2
        self.n1 = BookNote.objects.create(text="N1", book=self.b2, user=self.u1)
        BookNote.objects.create(text="N2", book=self.b2, user=self.u2)
        BookNote.objects.create(text="N3", book=self.b1, user=self.u2)

    def test_on_multiple(self):
        q =  Book.objects.all().annotate(
                usernote=FilteredRelation('booknote', condition=Q(booknote__user=self.u1)),
                usernote_text=F('usernote__text'),
                usernote_id=F('usernote'),
                ).order_by('id')
        print(q.query)
        self.assertEqual(q.count(), Book.objects.count())
        self.assertIsNone(q[0].usernote_text)
        self.assertEqual( q[1].usernote_text, self.n1.text)
        self.assertIsNone(q[2].usernote_text)

    def test_on_multiple_prefetch(self):
        @property
        def usernote(self):
            return self._usernote[0] if self._usernote else None
        Book.usernote = usernote
        q = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch(
            'booknote_set',
            queryset=BookNote.objects.filter(user=self.u1),
            to_attr='_usernote'
            )).order_by('id')

        self.assertEqual(q.count(), Book.objects.count())
        self.assertIsNone(q[0].usernote)
        self.assertEqual( q[1].usernote.text, self.n1.text)
        self.assertIsNone(q[2].usernote)
```

Comment: I still use django 1.11, and I try tried the second way. I get a very large queryset containing many duplicates of the Book table. This is the query django produces:  SELECT `app_book`.`id`, `app_book`.`name`, CASE WHEN `app_booknote`.`user_id` = 9 THEN `app_booknote`.`text` ELSE NULL END AS `usernote_text` FROM `app_book` LEFT OUTER JOIN `app_booknote` ON (`app_book`.`id` = `app_booknote`.`book_id`) ORDER BY `app_book`.`id` ASC

Comment: `SELECT app_book.id, app_book.name, CASE WHEN app_booknote.user_id = 9 THEN app_booknote.text ELSE NULL END AS usernote_text FROM app_book LEFT OUTER JOIN app_booknote ON (app_book.id = app_booknote.book_id) ORDER BY app_book.id ASC`  , I get `len(qs) = 226`, Book table has only 9 rows.. Maybe that is a bug in django 1.11?

Comment: Quite right on the 1.11 version not quite working right, and I can't seem to tweak it to get it to be correctly distinct. I'm removing it. Use the FilteredRelation or Prefetch objects instead.

Comment: How Prefetch works here? I can't use FilteredRelation because it's Django 2.0, this project still uses python 2.7

Comment: And even when I use Book.objects.raw(), I can't add an annotation, I get `None`s..